# How to replace one field of table with another?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a problem with my self-made search page.
There is 2 tables:

```
**name status**
Kevin 111       <-table1
Lucas 222

**id  data**
111 student     <-table2
222 pupil
```

So u need query that will give me table like that:

```
Kevin student
Lucas pupil
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.data 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.status = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.name
```

Comment: @SergiiRechmp: do my answer address your problem? Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, than you very much!. I Voted, and was departed to the other office, and then forgot to answer You. Thanks again :)